# C or Objective-C equivalent of Java's Integer.toOctalString()?

Tags: objective-c, c

Is there is an equivalent in C or Objective-C to do the following (taken from Java)

Integer.toOctalString(some_int)

Answer (score 2):

In C, you can use `char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );` with a base of 8.

Answer (score 1):

To create a NSString object, use:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%o", some_int];
```

Answer (score 1):

And of course there's always the venerable sxprintf:

```
sprintf (mystring, "%o", i)
```